# undefined method `payment_required?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`enter code here`on rails 7 and ruby version 3.2.0
my method returns nil even though it got data.
i am following a tutorial to build an app.

in my bookings view new.html.erb has
`<% if @booking_type.payment_required? %>`

and the bookings controller

```rb
 def new
  @booking = Booking.new
  @booking_type = BookingType.find_by(name: params[:booking_type])
end

def booking_params
 params.require(:booking).permit(:booking_type_id, :status, :name, :email, :start_at, :end_at, :notes)
end
```

Booking_types Controller params

```rb
def booking_type_params
      params.require(:booking_type).permit(:name, :location, :description, :color, :duration, :payment_required, :price, :user_id)
    end
```

After creating a the booking_type instance in the bookings controller

```rb
@booking_type = BookingType.find_by(name: params[:booking_type])
```

for the payment_required method in view, i still get undefined method `payment_required?' for nil:NilClass

Comment: I don't see where `booking_params` is used, so not sure what that's for. You create a `Booking`, not a `BookingType` in the code shown--what makes you think there's data?

Comment: @DaveNewton sorry i have edited my post to include booking_types_params from the booking_types controller

Comment: Okay, but it's not clear how any of the code shown here is related. If `@booking_type` is `nil` then no data is being returned from the DB for the query you're making, or you're looking in the wrong file, or you're running the wrong code.

Comment: well, `BookingType.all`  returns data  like `id: 2, name: "30 mins"`  but the cause of the nil is somehow about my query and i don't know if its implemented wrongly. `BookingType.find_by(name: params[:booking_type])`

Comment: What’s in your params?

Comment: `def booking_type_params` 
      `params.require(:booking_type).permit(:name, :location, :description, :color,` `:duration, :payment_required, :price, :user_id)`
    `end'`      the params are added in the main post

Comment: What’s in the params **received by the action**? What’s shown in the log or debugger? If the retrial is failing then it’s not getting the data you think it is.

Comment: in the log;  `Processing by BookingsController#new as HTML `                                  `Parameters: {"booking_type"=>"30-min", "booking_link"=>"jsmith"}`

Comment: `”30-min” != "30 mins”`

Answer (score 0):

In the method:

```
 def new
  @booking = Booking.new
  @booking_type = BookingType.find_by(name: params[:booking_type])
end
```

It's expected to receive a `booking_type` parameter. If the parameter is not set or there is no BookingType record with that name, the `@booking_type` variable will be nil, resulting in the `undefined method` payment_required?' for nil:NilClass` error.